# I want maven to use JRE system Library [JavaSE 1.8] always while creating new maven quickstart project

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

I have jdk/jre 1.8 installed on my windows system. In Eclipse whenever I create a quick-start maven project, the project gets created with JRE System Library[J2SE 1.5]. I am fed up of this problem tried to change the execution environment by doing right click on above JRE library-properties and changing the execution environment to 1.8 but again if I update this maven project, the JRE system library goes back again to J2SE 1.5, I also tried changing the compiler compliance to 1.8 which was earlier set to java 10 and also did adding the source and target tag with version 1.8 inside plugin tag of pom.xml but this was also a temporary solution. As when I create a new maven project it sets the default JRE system Library[J2SE 1.5]. Please Provide me with a permanent fix where whenever i create a new maven project, it should be created with JRE System Library[JavaSE 1.8].

Comment: The proper way is to tell Maven how it should invoke `javac` by configuring the maven-compiler-plugin.  Most IDE's will pick that up and choose the appropriate configuration (which incidentially overrides any change you have made yourself).

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to `pom.xml` to configure which JDK version you would want to use:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

or the followings:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

It is because when you do `Maven --> Update Project` in Eclipse , Eclipse 's maven plugin will use what you define in `pom.xml` to update the setting of the eclipse project. If you don't specify above settings , the default is to use JDK 1.5 (before `maven-compiler-plugin` version 3.8.0) or JDK 1.6 (3.8.0+)

> Basically I want maven to use JDK 1.8 by default. So that i wont need
>   to change pom.xml contents again and again while making a new project

If you do not want to change any settings related JDK version in `pom.xml` after creating a project , you may consider to [create your own archetype](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) to fully customize what `pom.xml` looks like after creating an project. Or a more simple way is to search some Java8 archetype created by others and simply use it such as  [this](https://github.com/mikolak-net/java8-quickstart-archetype).

Refer [this](https://o7planning.org/en/11253/create-an-empty-maven-web-app-project-in-eclipse) for how to create a Maven project with an specific archetype using Eclipse. You may probably need to click "Add Archetype" to configure the require information when you use that archetype for the first time. For example , for [this](https://github.com/mikolak-net/java8-quickstart-archetype) archetype, you have to configure the following for the 1st time:

```
archetypeGroupId=pl.org.miki 
archetypeArtifactId=java8-quickstart-archetype 
archetypeVersion=1.0.0
```

Comment: So always when I create  a new Maven Project I have to do above stuff in pom.xml file. Well I know this technique but what i was searching for is I want to change the maven settings to use JDK 1.8 by default. So that i wont have to add above code to pom.xml again and again when i create a new project

Comment: Basically I want maven to use JDK 1.8 by default. So that i wont need to change pom.xml contents again and again while making a new project

Comment: @ShubhamShingate . Ok . Understood your questions now. Please see my updates

Comment: The long term solution is to make your own customized version of an appropriate archetype.  Then you can make it exactly as you want it to be.